# How to make 2 different joins in one query (3 tables) on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

Let's say I have 3 tables and I want to join them like this:

```
table 1 join table 2 and table 2 join table 3
```

I'm trying the following code but I'm  getting an error of syntax.

`SELECT * from table1 join table2 and table2 join table3 
on  table1.id=table2.idA  and table2.idB=table3.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Study up a bit on SQL.  The syntax looks like:

```
select *
from table1 join
     table2
     on table1.id = table2.idA join
     table3  
     on table2.idB = table3.id;
```

This is very basic `JOIN` syntax and should be covered in any tutorial, documentation, book, paper or whatever that you are using to learn SQL.